# From where does the source jar load in Axis webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, classpath, axis

So I have this axis2-based webservice in aar-file which I build myself with ant. when I build it I specify jar files location. Particularly "rt.jar", I place it inside my lib folder and build my classes with javac. When I delete rt.jar from my lib folder javac does not build, so I know that jar file is used.

The problem is when I debug my webservice and try to understand where my WSBindingProvider class loads from using code below, it says that is loads from c:/program files/java/jre1.8/... even thought I do not use jre (not jdk) libraries anywhere inside my project.

Can anybody explain how does it work when certain class being used in build class file? Is Axis takes it from jre somehow? Or maybe tomcat?

```
Class klass = WSBindingProvider.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes from `rt.jar` are always used both by the JRE and `javac`. If your code only compiles if you add `rt.jar` to the class path, then that means that the `rt.jar` in question is from a different Java version than javac.

Comment: That is true, I found out that is it not quite easy to override rt.jar location and it allways loads from jre home location. Thank you for answering.